# oracle 3 tier architecture error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I’m working on asp.net c# oracle database connection using 3-Tier architecture. On my business layer class I’m getting this error. System.StackOverflowException was unhandled

I followed a tutorial using sql database and all worked fine with no error now I need to implement using oracle database.

Here is part of the code where I’m getting error

```
    public class BusSurvey
{
    DbAccess _dbAccess = new DbAccess();
    private DataSet _SurveyDS = new DataSet();
    public DataSet SurveyDS
    {
        get
        {
            return SurveyDS;
        }
        set
        {
            SurveyDS = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of `property` and `field` are same so change the field name

```
    private DataSet _SurveyDS = new DataSet();
    public DataSet SurveyDS
    {
        get
        {
            return _SurveyDS;  <--- here 
        }
        set
        {
            _SurveyDS = value; <--- here
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user1084949 - the database in use has no bearing on this.  As written in your post you've got an infinite loop in your property accessors - the 'get' accessor calls itself instead of returning the actual field you're trying to wrap, and the setter calls the getter which then goes into its infinite loop.

Comment: @AVD thank u for the help I thought I need to use diffrent name . it worked :)